# How to know Which reference has related to ATL100.dll in C# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, dependency-walker, cognex

**Update**

**environment : .NET 4 and Winform C# application.**

I want to know which reference has related to **ATL100.dll** in my C# application ? When I use "DependencyWalker" or "TaskManager", I can see this module on my application. However, I do not know which reference is related to this module. Do you have any idea ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using Cognex.VisionPro;
using Cognex.VisionPro.Blob;
using Cognex.VisionPro.Caliper;
using Cognex.VisionPro.Exceptions;
using Cognex.VisionPro.ImageFile;
using Cognex.VisionPro.ImageProcessing;
using Cognex.VisionPro.PMAlign;
using DBSubClass;
using Jai_FactoryDotNET;
using LogManager;
using MediatorPattern;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATL is a library for C++ code, typically used to implement a COM server.  Your C# project does not directly use C++ code.  But it is pretty safe to assume that a managed wrapper named Cognex.VisionPro does.  Image processing libraries are almost always written in C or C++.  ATL makes it easy to make that library accessible from any language.  COM provides the glue.

Be sure to use the installer provided by Cognex.  Or ask them for manual install instructions.

Answer (score 0):

In C# an `assembly` is a `dll` or `exe` file and on a conceptual level may be seen as a *module*. You're confusing the terms a little bit.

Maybe you have a namespace and want to know in which dll file it resides?
Please amend you question, it is a bit confused.